# How does HotJar generate their recordings?

Tags: javascript, hotjar

Tracking mouse movement/scroll/click events is easy but how do they save the screen and keep it in sync so well?

The pages are rendered very quite well (at least for static HTML pages, haven't tested on Angular or any SPA), the sync is almost perfect.

To generate and upload a 23fps recording of my screen (1920x1080) it would take about 2Mbps of bandwidth. Maybe when recording only when there are some mouse events it would still take some 300-500Kbps on average? That seems way too much...

Comment: i believe this is actually a very good question. If you google around people will tell you "it's impossible to record snapshots of web pages using JS". In my opnion, this question is just a specific case of the more general "how to record web pages using JS?"

Comment: From my understanding, they store HTML + CSS and mouse events. That is, they do not record a video but rather re-render and replay events. How that is all accomplished in the quality that HotJar shows .. I have no idea. They touch upon their way of communicating events without degrading performance here: https://docs.hotjar.com/docs/will-hotjar-slow-down-my-site

Answer (score 26, accepted):

HTML content and DOM changes get pumped through a websocket and stored by Hotjar (minus sensitive information such as form inputs from the user, unless you've whitelisted them), the CSS isn't stored (it gets loaded by you when you watch the recording).

Because they're only recording user activity and DOM changes, there's a lot less data to record than if they were capturing a full video. The downside is that some Javascript driven widgets won't function correctly in the replay.

Relevant information from Hotjar docs:

> - When it comes to recordings, changes to the page are captured using the MutationObserver API which is built-in into every modern browser.
>     This makes it efficient since the change itself is already happening
>     on the page and the browser MutationObserver API allows us to record
>     this change which we then parse and also send through the websocket.
> - At regular short intervals, every 100ms or 10 times per second, the cursor position and scroll position are recorded. Clicks are recorded
>     when they happen, capturing the position of the cursor relative to the
>     element being clicked. These are functions which in no way hinder a
>     user's experience as they only capture the location of the pointer
>     when a click happens or every 100ms. The events are sent to the Hotjar
>     servers through frames within the websocket, which is more efficient
>     than sending XHR requests at regular intervals.

Source: https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009335727-Will-Hotjar-Slow-Down-My-Site-

Comment: `the CSS isn't stored (it gets loaded by you when you watch the recording)` does this mean we're not seeing an accurate reflection of what the visitor actually sees? my site uses CSS Grid and i'm sure some of my visitors are using IE, but the videos never show anything broken

Comment: @MattSaunders i love that you just went with grid in 2018 :)

For anyone coming, yes, i found that their videos are just interactions overlapped on top of this same image. It could be done with some browser soft like puppeteer or similar.